# Colocar chave criptográfica fixa

Tags: java, android, segurança, criptografia

O código abaixo está funcionando perfeitamente tanto pra criptografia quanto para decifrar, porém, ao fechar o app e colocar o código gerado antes de fecha-lo (abro o app criptografo uma palavra e fecho o app e ao voltar colo para decifrar a mensagem).

Ocorre que nao funciona quando faço isso e minha intensão é que funcione, tanto fechando e abrindo tanto para outro celular que tenha o mesmo APP instalado.

Creio deveria colocar uma key fixa em vez da `"SecretKeySpec"`.

Mas nao estou sabendo implementar uma maneira de deixar a chave de criptográfia fixa em vez de ser gerada seria por ex `"123"`, para que pudesse decifrar a mensagem gerada de qualquer outro cell com o app ou do mesmo celular ( no caso de fechar e abrir).

```
import android.util.Base64;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * Created by thiago.goncalves on 22/02/2016.
 */
public class Encripta {

    private final Cipher cipher;
    private  final SecretKeySpec key ;
    private AlgorithmParameterSpec spec;
    public static final String SEED_16_CHARACTER = "U1MjU1M0FDOUZ.Qz";


    public Encripta() throws Exception {
        // hash password with SHA-256 and crop the output to 128-bit for key
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(SEED_16_CHARACTER.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);



        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

        byte[] key  = "secret".getBytes();
      //  String IV     = "12345678";
        spec = getIV();
    }

    public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV() {
        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
        ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        return ivParameterSpec;
    }



    public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String encryptedText = new String(Base64.encode(encrypted,
                Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");

        return encryptedText;
    }

    public String decrypt(String cryptedText) throws Exception {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(cryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
        String decryptedText = new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");

        return decryptedText;
    }

}
```

Comment: Não use um IV fixo! O IV tem que ser aleatório ou, no mínimo, diferente cada vez que você encriptar um dado novo (globalmente - você *nunca* deve repetir um IV durante todo o ciclo de vida da sua chave). Caso contrário, toda a segurança da criptografia vai por água abaixo...

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade sua key já está fixa!

Perceba que para criar sua SecretKeySpec, você utiliza os bytes de `SEED_16_CHARACTER`.

Resumindo o contrutor:

```
//cria um MessageDigest de SHA-256
 MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
// pega os bytes de sua chave
final byte[] seedBytes = SEED_16_CHARACTER.getBytes("UTF-8”);
// set no digest
digest.update(seedBytes);

cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding”);
// cria uma chave com os bytes da chave
key = new SecretKeySpec(seedBytes, "AES");
```

Realizei alguns testes, e aqui funcionou perfeitamente, 
Encriptei em um e desencriptei em outro sem problemas !

Segue o teste:

**Encrypta.java**

```
public class Encrypta {

    private final Cipher cipher;
    private  final SecretKeySpec key ;
    private AlgorithmParameterSpec spec;
    public static final String SEED_16_CHARACTER = "Olá Mundo 12345";


    public Encrypta() throws Exception {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        final byte[] seedBytes = SEED_16_CHARACTER.getBytes("UTF-8");
        digest.update(seedBytes);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        key = new SecretKeySpec(seedBytes, "AES");
        spec = getIV();
    }

    public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV() {
        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
        ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        return ivParameterSpec;
    }



    public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String encryptedText = new String(Base64.encode(encrypted,
                Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");

        return encryptedText;
    }

    public String decrypt(String cryptedText) throws Exception {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(cryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
        String decryptedText = new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
        return decryptedText;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText editText;
    private EditText textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = EditText.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.editText));
        textView = EditText.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.textView));
        Button.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                encripta();
            }
        });
        Button.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.button2)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                desencripta();
            }
        });
    }


    private void desencripta(){
        final String txt = editText.getText().toString();
        try {
            final Encrypta encrypta = new Encrypta();
            String result = encrypta.decrypt(txt);
            textView.setText(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    private void encripta(){
        final String txt = editText.getText().toString();
        try {
            final Encrypta encrypta = new Encrypta();
            String result = encrypta.encrypt(txt);
            textView.setText(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ceabs.library.shared.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Caso ainda não consiga, verifique as `Strings` que estão sendo geradas, para verificar se existe alguma diferença.

Comment: Mais um vez obrigado Thiago... Cara eu ainda to estudando bem o código mas não sei explicar o porque estava dando errado, percebi algumas diferenças nas criaçoes e chamadas dos txts, edits etc ja que eu esto usando um... Mas seu codigo me ajudou muito, vou estudar pra tentar melhorar aqui mas agora esta funcionando da maneira que eu pretendia criar, claro é para fins de estudo nada profissional ainda. Obrigado pela ajuda!